# Отобразить веб-страницу в chromecast

Tags: веб-программирование, chromecast

Реально ли вывести на Chromecast веб-страницу без компьютера и без демонстрации экрана смартфона? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, к сожалению, это невозможно

> Это возможно. Вот https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myfknoll.cast.browser&hl=en

Comment: Возможно. Но с некоторыми ограничениями. Посмотрите например https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myfknoll.cast.browser&hl=en
К сожалению, ни Гугл ни Яндекс это приложение не загружает (X-Frames are not supported by Chromecast)

Comment: Круто, большое спасибо. Теперь буду знать. Еще бы исходники этого чуда или просто узнать, как это реализовано

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически такое приложение разработать возможно, но пока этого никто не сделал.
Основная проблема в том, что при любой интерактивности, например, при движении курсора, будет лаг в несколько секунд.
Если очень нужно, можно использовать MHL, в котором этого ограничения нет
**Дополнение:** MHL это не только mirroring, также возможно настроить два независимых экрана.
Презентация на эту тему: http://www.slideshare.net/commonsguy/secondscreen-support-in-android-42/
Если ваша веб-страница статичная, может быть имеет смысл воспользоваться одним из *Website Screenshot Generators* и отправлять полученную картинку на телевизор

Comment: что значит MHL?

Comment: Mobile High-Definition Link. Поддерживается не всеми устройствами, сигнал передаётся по проводу.

Comment: а вы до конца дочитали мой вопрос?

Comment: Да, все два предложения. Что не так? Кстати, расскажите подробнее что собираетесь сделать

Comment: я в вопросе написал, что демонстрация экрана смартфона не подходит. С MHL можно только экран демонстрировать. И каким боком там Chromecast тоже не понимаю. Я собираюсь выводить страницу с локального сервера на Chromecast

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: тоесть, как я понял, только с chromecast'ом и смартфоном у меня ничего не поличится. Верно?

Comment: Зависит от того, что именно Вы пытаетесь сделать

Comment: отобразить динамическую веб-страницу

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос подробным описанием работы приложения, которое Вы хотите разработать или задайте новый. На данный момент вопрос слишком абстрактный